# Rails Nginx Unicorn Capistrano - deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, capistrano, unicorn

I had been at this for hours now and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am using Ruby 2.1.5, Rails 4.2.0, Ubuntu 14.04 server (on digitalocean), and here's my gemfile for the rest:

```
...
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.4.0'
gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
gem 'capistrano-passenger'
...
```

I followed the configuration instructions found in these two tutorials: [tutorial 1](http://www.rubytreesoftware.com/resources/ruby-on-rails-41-ubuntu-1404-server-deployment) and [tutorial 2](http://www.rubytreesoftware.com/resources/securely-setup-ubuntu-1404-server).

They have to be a bit out of date because capistrano in the video doesn't say that it needs capistrano-passenger, but on my machine it does. I try running.

However, everything in the tutorials work fine except for the very last statement, deploying the server with this command `bin/cap production deploy`. I get an error that says

```
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@0.0.0.0: cp exit status: 1
cp stdout: Nothing written
cp stderr: cp: cannot stat ‘/opt/www/myapp/releases/20150326054249/public/assets/manifest*’: No such file or directory

SSHKit::Command::Failed: cp exit status: 1
cp stdout: Nothing written
cp stderr: cp: cannot stat ‘/opt/www/myapp/releases/20150326054249/public/assets/manifest*’: No such file or directory

Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:backup_manifest
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deploy@0.0.0.0: cp exit status: 1
cp stdout: Nothing written
cp stderr: cp: cannot stat ‘/opt/www/myapp/releases/20150326054249/public/assets/manifest*’: No such file or directory
```

Since I have seen other tutorials with similar instructions, I feel like it is all right, I'm just missing something small.

Also, after it fails, it somehow uninstall capistrano. Because if I try to run it again, I get this error:

```
cap aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- capistrano/rails
/home/jeremy/421_WEBAPP/myapp/Capfile:6:in `require'
/home/jeremy/421_WEBAPP/myapp/Capfile:6:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Somebody please help, I can't pull my hair out over this any longer

Comment: 1. can you tell which ssh kit is installed   
2.You deployment script plz remove the server credentials and post

Comment: I just installed ssh the way it show [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) on github. I don't understand part 2 of your comment

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure it out?

Comment: Interesting, me too. @Anjan

Comment: I think it has something to do with sprockets 3.0.0 and an [issue](https://github.com/capistrano/rails/issues/33) with capistrano-rails.

Comment: Same here. Very interested in the solution. :(

Comment: I believe these Gists would help you to fix the issue. https://gist.github.com/ParthivSavani/1a7f17b513f5b3c6afdc0aab96c9ed37
https://gist.github.com/ParthivSavani/bc21f7ed2e33b65f738f0d2829e7e9a2